# Implement Nativescript Admob plugin to load on startup from github sample code

Tags: admob, nativescript

I'm trying to modify the nativescript-admob-demo-app (https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-admob-demo) using the nativescript-admob-plugin (admob) to insert a SMART_BANNER when the app starts up rather than when pressing a button. I've tried a few methods detailed below:

Could anyone help show me the code that would do this or pesudocode, or perhaps just the method and I'll implement it? Thank you!

I've tried the following,

Creating a placeholder element on the screen and constructing the helloworld model and then assigning that function to exports (in main-view-model.js).

Calling the admob.createBanner from the main-page.js and exporting that

Adding the view tag in the main-page.js and getting my first tabview, then calling that.

Creating the model in main-page.js by importing it from main-page-view.xml and calling it inside the pageLoaded function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I understand your question, you want to use a `<PlaceHolder>` to construct a view (admob) when the page loads. So what I would do is...

### XML

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">
    <StackLayout>
       <Placeholder creatingView="createAdmob" />
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

### JS

```
function createAdmob (args) {
    var admob = //construct the admob code and assign it to this var.
    args.view = admob;
}
exports.createAdmob = createAdmob;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Brad! I currently have the exact XML:
and in my 'main-page.js' I have:
`function createAdmob (args) { 
  var testAdvert = admob.createBanner({
  testing: true,
  size: admob.AD_SIZE.SMART_BANNER,
  iosBannerId: "ca-app-pub-XXX",
  androidBannerId: "ca-app-pub-XXX", 
    margins: {
        
      // if both are set, top wins
       
      //top: 10
        
      bottom: 50
      
    }
 
  });
   
 args.view = testAdvert;

}

exports.createAdmob = createAdmob;`

I get this a method onCreateView failed this._nativeView.getLayoutParams is not a function'.

Comment: My console also prints this: JS: Error in admob.createBanner: Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.

Comment: The first error you mention '_nativeView.getLayoutParams', I believe is going to be an issue with the plugin. Might try opening an issue on the repo and see if the author can help you out. I haven't used the plugin myself so I'm not an authority on it at the moment.

Comment: Awesome. I think you're right, I'll open it. Otherwise, you're method was spot on - just the plugin did not want to play nice. Thank you for your help Brad!